# Is there a way to ensure a generic type will be a base class of another class in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

So here is my problem:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    protected List<List<???>> _groups;

    public Animal(List<List<???>> groups)
    {
        _groups = groups;

        foreach (List<???> group in groups)
        {
            group.Add(this);    
        }
    }
}


public abstract class Mammal : Animal
{
    public Mammal(List<List<???>> groups) : base(groups)
    {
    }
}

public class Dog : Mammal
{
    public Dog(List<List<???>> groups) : base(groups)
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have an `Animal` abstract class and its subclasses like `Mammal`. These subclasses will also have their own, possibly concrete subclasses like `Dog`. The animal class has a `_groups` field. A group of animals could look like this:

```
List<Mammal> mammals = new List<Mammal>();

//         or

List<Animal> twoLegsAnimals = new List<Animal>();
```

When creating an animal you can pass it all the groups it belongs to. The problem (as you can see by the `???` used as generics) is how do you pass the animal the groups so that it can't add itself into a group it does not belong to (eg. a `Duck` cannot be in the mammals group) AND so that it can add itself into all groups it needs to.

I tried doing something like this:

```
public class Dog : Mammal
{
    public Dog(List<List<T>> groups) : base(groups) where Dog : T
    {
    }
}
```

this would logicaly make sense because you can pass the dog only the groups it could be in. The problem is that C# does not allow me to say that `Dog` has to extend `T`. Basically `T` needs to be a base of `Dog`. Any way to get around this?

**EDIT:** Ok there is a lot of confusion going on with the "group" concept. By group I just mean a list of animals. For example a Deers and Sheeps could be added to preys group. A Wolf could then have a `Hunt(List<Animal> preys)` method that would kill a random prey. He would use a Kill method on the prey (available on all animals) that will remove the prey from all the groups it is in. I don't really see any other way to achieve this kind of interaction.

**EDIT2:** Sorry I figured out what I wrote wrong. Originaly I wrote:

```
List<List<Mammal>> mammals = new List<List<Mammal>>();

//         or

List<List<Animal>> twoLegsAnimals = new List<List<Animal>>();
```

I hope "groups" makes more sense now.

Comment: I don't get your concept of a "group". What exactly is a group and why does an animal have multiple of them? And why do you need a list of lists of these?

Comment: You sure meant `Dog : Mammal`, not `Dog : Animal`

Comment: Technically, you can just make your `Animal`-class generic and use the generic argument within your list. However I don't get what an "Animal of WhateverType" should mean.

Comment: This is often referenced as a `THISTYPE` or `Self` concept and it's not currently implemented in C#. It also almost immediately starts running into variance issues which is why it's not trivial to put it usefully into the type system.

Comment: Why have groups as member of the base class? The classification/grouping doesn’t make sense

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain By group I just mean a list of animals. For example a _Deers_ and _Sheeps_ could be added to _preys_ group. A _Wolf_ could then have a _Hunt(List<Animal> preys)_ method, and do whatever he needs. I don't really see any other way to achieve this kind of interaction.

Comment: The Animal implementation shouldn't know anything about the groups - the responsibility for adding particular animals to particular groups belongs in a different class.

Comment: @Anitoni It sounds like you want some kind of entity-component system. Animals of type Deer would have their Ids put into a list of Prey (probably via an event handler that listens for created events). Get rid of the deep inheritance and embrace composition. Can you ENFORCE that entities of type Deer don't get added to Predators? No. Nor should you. Maybe there's a really rabid deer? Besides, it's not the Deer's responsibility to identify itself as prey.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a type constraint like this:

```
public abstract class Animal<T> where T : Animal<T>
{
    protected List<List<T>> _groups;

    public Animal(List<List<T>> groups)
    {
        _groups = groups;

        if (this is T x)
        {
            foreach (List<T> group in groups)
            {
                group.Add(x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then, e.g. the `Dog` class will be declared as:

```
public class Dog : Animal<Dog> { … }
```

As a matter of course, you can't prevent the user passing in e.g. a `Fish : Animal<Fish>` into `Dog`. What you could do, is a runtime check in the constructor:

```
public Animal(List<List<T>> groups)
{
    if (typeof(T) != this.GetType()) throw …;
```

*Side note: Your decomposition looks pretty awkward. Groups of animals seem to be a concept that spans beyond a particular animal class, and so having groups being a member of an individual animal looks very counterintuitive from the data structure design perspective.*

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEAsBuWsQGZEEMAjAZwBcAnfAY1OTEQEEA7ASwFt8AbAHgBUA+RAHcAFgFNyYxL0QAuRqw48BsAN6xEmxAAdyAe1JiaYgCaIAMizLdL1gYID6Ac30BXbcUwwNW3AvZcABS2pDZWofaILnruxACUPprqMFqpiM5uHogAvFGZnlgpaZoAZnqS1CKIweF8gtHuiCxMeTEeCUXFycXFDdoAdAwmJoGkIlZx6KmJaQC+M/Mwi9h4RGSUNHSIALL4bEpy/krcu/tc/GozfqdKNdYhJ3tK/PX5cYeE+MRigX3xM90tItlnA8OBEAARPROQ7MAI8KFOC4wQGaPyIu6hB6Il6tWLveSfb6/N4AhawRZAA)

Comment: @canton7 Thank's for pointing out the minor issue, which just emphasizes how _awkward_ the design is. Updated my answer accordingly. Otherwise, _yes, I'm sure_: the core of the OP's answer leads to a generic type constraint; a simple type cast error is easily fixable.

Comment: @canton7 _“Casting through object will probably work however”_ is a terrible piece of advice.

Comment: Eh, if you've already ensured the cast won't fail by other means (such as checking whether `typeof(T) == GetType()`), then it's just a necessary evil to tell the compiler that you know what you're doing

Comment: @canton7 Yes. However, I did not think of the cast in the first place, so you were right it was needed there in order for the code to compile.